# Which flag should I use when enabling MSAA in Directx9?

Tags: c++, directx, device, flags, msaa

I enabled MSAA when creating a device in Directx9 and had to remove the D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER flag. However, since I removed this flag, SweetFX does not work. What can I do for it? ReShade works but I need SweetFX, so I want to solve this problem. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: Hey there, a quick warning: Your questions tend to be getting next-to-no traction, and of the 9 visible questions you've asked, only one has been well received. Your account is in danger of the server applying a "question ban". A common thread in the questions I've looked at so far is they are incomplete, lacking enough information to produce good, concrete answers likely to be helpful to future askers.

Comment: I recommend giving [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) a read-through and taking advantage of the [accompanying checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Comment: @user4581301 Why would it be against the rules if I opened a topic to get information about a situation? Many people like me can see these and similar issues and solve the question mark in their minds. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Nothing against the rules here, or in the questions I reviewed, but a question is expected to help future programmers in addition to the asker. Off topic questions get closed. Questions that site visitors don't deem useful, didn't help them or result in them learning a new trick for the toolbox, don't get upvotes. The server, no humans involved, runs an undisclosed algorithm counting up the up and downvotes, for content deleted and undeleted and unless the result crosses some usefulness threshold, you'll find how often you can post slows until it reaches one post per six months.

Comment: Over time questions that don't get an immediate bump from readers who think the question is useful, and probably visited to see if it was something they can answer well, could get upvoted by future visitors. But if the initial visitors don't upvote or answer, you are counting on future visitors, and that's mostly folk looking for an answer. If there's no answer, the question tends to languish in limbo. You have several questions that have been answered. Over time that'll work to your benefit, but while you wait you need to be careful about how and what you ask.